# Swift UITextField check text from second character

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I have ViewController, that have 2 text fields on it. View Controller is a UITextFieldDelegate. I check values from this fields, and if they are valid, than I activate return from this view controller button. The problem is that validation starts from second character: if I try to enter values in each field, button became inactive till I enter second character, but if I delete this character after I enter it, return button stays active. I found that problem was occurred by `checkIfAddingAvailable()`. Where I got wrong?

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    guard let oldTextString = textField.text else {
        return true
    }
    let oldText = oldTextString as NSString
    let newString = oldText.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string) as NSString

    if newString.length > 0 {
       let _ = checkIfAddingAvailable()
    } else {
       addFoodButton.isEnabled = false
    }
    return true
}

func checkIfAddingAvailable() -> Bool {
    //TODO: implement valid checking of posibility to add food
    guard let foodName = foodNameField.text else { return false }
    guard !foodName.isEmpty else {
        return false
    }

    guard let foodShelfLife = shelfLifeField.text else { return false }
    guard !foodShelfLife.isEmpty else {
        return false
    }
    guard let foodShelfLifeIntoDouble = Double(foodShelfLife) else { return false }
    guard foodShelfLifeIntoDouble > 0 else {
        return false
    }
    addFoodButton.isEnabled = true
    return true
}
```

Comment: you should pass  newString String to   checkIfAddingAvailable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should pass newstring  to checkIfAddingAvailable at shouldChangeCharactersIn  because textField not have final text yet

adjust the code for your text fields

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        guard let oldTextString = textField.text else {
            return true
        }
        let oldText = oldTextString as NSString
        let newString = oldText.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string) as NSString

        if newString.length > 0 {
            let _ = checkIfAddingAvailable(newString)
        } else {
            addFoodButton.isEnabled = false
        }
        return true
    }

    func checkIfAddingAvailable(_ foodNameFieldText :String) -> Bool {
        //TODO: implement valid checking of posibility to add food
        guard let foodName = foodNameFieldText else { return false }
        guard !foodName.isEmpty else {
            return false
        }

        guard let foodShelfLife = shelfLifeField.text else { return false }
        guard !foodShelfLife.isEmpty else {
            return false
        }
        guard let foodShelfLifeIntoDouble = Double(foodShelfLife) else { return false }
        guard foodShelfLifeIntoDouble > 0 else {
            return false
        }
        addFoodButton.isEnabled = true
        return true
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. Because I need to check values from both text fields at same time, I am already solve this with passing both replacing string and text field that have been modified, and after that checking values from not mutated field and this.Its not obvious that text field first call this method and only after that take new value to textField.text.

Answer (score 0):

Please add this method on your code:

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    if textField == yourTextFieldName {  
        if textField.text?.characters.count > 0 {
            let _ = checkIfAddingAvailable()
        } else {
            addFoodButton.isEnabled = false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I must check values from both text field at the same time while I am editing this fields, and this method is called after the text field resigns its first responder status.

Comment: you are looking change method on every character type or remove?

Comment: On every character: if user starts to enter data to second textField, and data in first text field is already entered, than done button become enable.